# Add a popup text view to a SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I am creating a SpriteKit game and want to be able to take advantage of textAlerts - like all the games I grew up playing. I also want them to be flexible so I can subclass them and add them throughout my game - I am not sure how to do this and so would be very grateful of any advice.

There are a number of ways that I have started to look into:

**Use another SKScene**

The idea here would be to add another scene immediately on top of our current one. This would have a faded out background and would be configured with the text to be displayed. This seems like the wrong approach

**Use an SKNode**

I could create a custom node and initialise it with my specific text. I would then disable movement and add the node at the bottom of the screen. I would then customise the actions that occur when it is tapped.

**Use an SKLabel**

SKLabels are designed to show text so these seem like a promising place to look. The issue is that I want to add an image into the popup view (this a headshot of the person you are talking to) and so it doesn't feel like I should be able to inject an image in.

**Use something else**

I don't know what this might be. Is what I am trying to do easy or harder than I think?

My problem is that I come from a swift background so am struggling to convert to a SpriteKit mindset. In Swift I would put together a custom UIView with all the UIKit components and add it to the screen. In SpriteKit we don't have the same tools so I don't know the right combinations to put together what I want.

Ideally I want to be able to configure the text popup with an array of text so that a conversation can be had with the user tapping for each new line.

[image]

Edit 1: What I have tried so far

Based on @ElTomatos comment I have experimented with adding a SKSpriteNode and an SKLabelNode on top of each other using the following code:

```
    guard let camera = camera else { return } 

    let dialogueBackground = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .red, size: CGSize(width: screenSize.width / camera.xScale, height: screenSize.height / 3 / camera.xScale))
    dialogueBackground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    dialogueBackground.zPosition = 50
    dialogueBackground.position = CGPoint(x: -screenSize.width, y: -screenSize.height)

    camera.addChild(dialogueBackground)

    let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello world")
    label.zPosition = 100
    label.position = CGPoint(x: -screenSize.width, y: 100 - screenSize.height)
    camera.addChild(label)
```

[image]

As you can see the view doesn't go to the edge of the screen. Is this something to do with the safe area? It's difficult to get the width and height as the camera doesn't have a CGSize we can use.

Comment: That's just an SKLabelNode object on top of an SKSpriteNode objject backed by SKTexture.  There's nothing special.

Comment: @ElTomato How do I configure it to be the same size as the camera I am using? How can I subclass it so I don't need to add a lot of boilerplate code each time. As someone new to SpriteKit there is very little documentation on combining views like this. An answer going through some of the basics would be very appreciated - I have edited my question after trying what you suggested and a screenshot.

Comment: It's been more than a year since I developed the last game.  So I don't remember the details.  But I guess it's up to the view controller that determines how the game scene is displayed.  If you set the right scale mode to the game scene, you will work with the same game size regardless of the device screen size.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the screenSize correctly? Do you use UIScreen.main.bounds? Also, for sklabel you can use .horizontalAlignment and .verticalAlignment for indentation.